# How to alter Image column on Sybase to NOT NULL

Tags: sybase

On a Sybase ASE 15.7 database I'm trying to modify a column type `Image` from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` (I'm using [SQSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqsh/) so `;` is a valid terminator):

```
create table LOB_TEST (XML image NULL);
alter table LOB_TEST modify XML image NOT NULL;
```

Error message:

```
Msg 13907, Level 16, State 1
Server 'MYSERVER', Line 1
ALTER TABLE 'LOB_TEST' failed. You cannot modify column 'XML' to TEXT/IMAGE/UNITEXT  type.
```

This works on an int type column:

```
create table NON_LOB_TEST (XML_ID int NULL);
alter table NON_LOB_TEST modify XML_ID int NOT NULL;
(0 rows affected)
```

Any clues why? I cannot find anything online. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to do itm spent about 1 hour... no way. Is it impossible to recreate your table defining some `default value` to your `image` column?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior in ASE 16

Comment: The whole point is to *not recreate* the table; what I posted is a simplified example that replicates the problem but the original table has 467M rows. Yes this can be done by using a `select into` or any other way that allows to copy/recreate data. Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text/image datatypes are very different internally from the other datatypes due to the way they are stored. Therefore, it is not a surprise that operations that work on an INT column do not work on a text/image column.

The documentation is not terribly clear on this point, but implicitly it sort of says that you cannot modify the nullability of a text/image column: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1600/doc/html/san1393050903443.html